# Imagemagick convert resize then crop

Tags: resize, imagemagick, crop

I have over 1000 images on different resolutions, (for example 1234x2122, 4400x5212 , etc) and I want to convert all of them to fixed 100x100 size, so.

1. first I need to resize the images keeping proportions, and get 100xA or Ax100, where A > 100 (it depends width and height of image, for some images width > height, and for some images height > width).
2. Crop this image to 100x100 from center

Is there a simple `convert` command, that I can use for all my images?

Comment: seems like what you want to do is similar to this http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=18545

Answer (score 74, accepted):

You would use the [area-fill](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/resize/#fill) (`^`) [geometry modifier](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-processing.php#geometry) on the `-resize` operation to unify the down-scale. For cropping the center, [`-extent`](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php?#extent) with [`-gravity Center`](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php?#gravity) will work.

```
convert input.jpg -resize 100x100^ \
                  -gravity Center  \
                  -extent 100x100  \
        output.jpg
```

**Update**

As Mark Setchell pointed out in the comments, the [`mogrify`](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/mogrify.php) utility can be leveraged to batch convert items.

```
mogrify -path ./path/to/write/results/ \
        -resize 100x100^ \
        -gravity Center  \
        -extent 100x100  \
        ./path/to/source/files/*
```

> [image: reminder] ***Reminder:*** Mogrify will overwrite original file with resulting image(s), unless you set the `-path` parameter.

Comment: Have my vote:-) Maybe mention `mogrify` if OP has 1000+ images?

Comment: @emcconville, is there way to accomplish this without loosing transparent background of an png?

Comment: I’ve found the solution ([src](https://makandracards.com/makandra/46467-imagemagick-how-to-auto-crop-and-or-resize-an-image-into-a-box)): `convert input.png -resize 100x100^ -gravity Center -background transparent -extent 100x100 output.png`

Comment: Is the answer exactly as Gor asked for? I.e., Gor asked for the central part without white space on either dimension, but reading the answer over and over, I have the feeling that the answer given as of Sep 8 '15 might have filled-blanks on either dimension. Am I right, anyone?

Comment: It doesn't work for me in 2022. The resulting image is not cropped around the centre (and it's sad that there are so few options for the rotation centre). I managed to rotate images in Pillow (Python), it allows for an arbitrary rotation centre.

Answer (score 4):

To keep the aspect ratio and don't fill anything (extent), rather crop from the longer edge which is out of aspect you could do

```
convert input.jpg -resize 100x100^ \
                  -gravity Center  \
                  -crop 100x100+0+0 +repage  \
        output.jpg
```

with option to crop more from one side if you like