# Image Magick Mogrify @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/3497 Permission Denied

Tags: image, powershell, imagemagick, image-manipulation, imagemagick-convert

I wanted to resize a batch of Image using ImageMagick.

I used this [this command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32466048/imagemagick-convert-crop-and-resize?answertab=votes#tab-top) found on stackOverflow.

There are two directory on the same level

- "img_resize" where I want to put my resized images.
- "image_models" where there are my images.

I used:

```
magick mogrify -path "img_resize" -resize 512x512 -gravity Center -extent 512x512 "image_models"
```

And got:

```
mogrify: unable to open image 'img_resize': Permission denied @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/3497.
mogrify: no decode delegate for this image format `' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/556.
```

I tried without using two directory:

```
cd image_models
magick mogrify -resize 512x512 -gravity Center -extent 512x512
```

It doesn't show errors; But still didn't do anything.

Therefore, the "convert" command work well. The issue come from mogrify.

I'm using windows 10. I used the Terminal and the Terminal run as Admin.

I also tried with ./dir instead of "dir"

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Remove all the unnecessary double-quotes throughout your first command and change the last parameter to `image_models\*`

Answer (score 1):

If your current directory is the base of your mentioned two folders, use relaive pathes and a wildcard for the source:

```
magick mogrify -path ".\img_resize\" -resize 512x512 -gravity Center -extent 512x512 ".\image_models\*"
```

Sample run in A:\Test folder:

```
> Get-ChildItem -Recurse

Verzeichnis: A:\test

Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
d-----       2019-06-11     11:30                image_models
d-----       2019-06-11     11:31                img_resize

    Verzeichnis: A:\test\image_models

Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----       2018-11-02     22:32         679624 AucklandOneTreeHillIanRushton_01.jpg
-a----       2018-11-02     22:32         529290 AucklandOneTreeHillIanRushton_02.jpg

    Verzeichnis: A:\test\img_resize

Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----       2019-06-11     11:31          53545 AucklandOneTreeHillIanRushton_01.jpg
-a----       2019-06-11     11:31          50687 AucklandOneTreeHillIanRushton_02.jpg
```

Comment: As Mentioned on the topic, I tried to apply the resize without -path argument, and It did not do anything. I'm guessing there is a issue other than the pah. However I tried your command and It did not do anything: img_resize dir is still empty.

Comment: Without a path the original files are overwritten. Depending on your current directory you need to supply a relative/absolute path with a wildcard. The above code and my described variant both do work here.

Comment: And ***WITHOUT*** `-path` argument that will stay so. For my originalworking  command the relative pathes rely on being **IN** the common parent of both folders.